# xslt format-date not working with format "Fri, 10 May 2019 01:15:00 GMT"

Tags: xslt-2.0, date-formatting

When using the format-date function on a date formatted like "Fri, 10 May 2019 01:15:00 GMT", I get an error:  Invalid date "Fri, 10 May 2019 01:15:00 GMT" (Non-numeric year component)

I would like to obtain a dd/MM/yyyy format .

Comment: Well, that function `format-date` works on the `xs:date` data type, not on arbitrary strings. In XSLT 3 you could parse your string with `parse-ietf-date('Fri, 10 May 2019 01:15:00 GMT')` into an `xs:dateTime` and then you could use `format-dateTime`. So which XSLT processor do you use, given that you have used the [tag:xslt-2.0] chances are you use Saxon 9 or Altova which since 2017 exist in versions supporting XSLT 3.

Answer (score 0):

If you use XSLT 2 chances are you use a processor like Saxon 9 or AltovaXML which have since 2017 (e.g. Saxon in release 9.8 or later or Altova in releas 2017 or later) updated to support XSLT 3 and XPath 3.1 where you could then make use of the `parse-ietf-date` function (https://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-functions/#func-parse-ietf-date) to parse your input string into a `xs:dateTime` on which you could then apply the `format-dateTime` function:

```
format-dateTime(parse-ietf-date('Fri, 10 May 2019 01:15:00 GMT'), '[D01]/[M01]/[Y0001]')
```

https://xqueryfiddle.liberty-development.net/6qM2e2m/1

Your current approach doesn't work as the `format-date` function works on `xs:date` and not on arbitrary formatted date strings. That particular format you have shown in your sample can be parsed by the `parse-ietf-date` function.